# extract column entry from matrix for time series

Tags: matlab, time-series

Is there a more robust way for the following problem:

```
d = 1+(20-1).*rand(365,5);
bthD = 1:5;
I = repmat(bthD',73,1);

for i = 1:length(d);
    q(i) = d(i,I(i));
end
```

Here, I are the indices that indicate which column of the matrix are required. q is the outcome where we have each row with the corresponding column number as specified by I. Is there an alternative way to find q?

modified question:

I have data:

```
d = 1+(20-1).*rand(365,5);
```

I would like to find the value in each row corresponding to the indices in I:

```
I = floor(1+(5-1).*rand(365,1));
```

This can easily be achieved by using a for loop:

```
for i = 1:length(d);
    q(i) = d(i,I(i));
end
```

However, I would like to find an alternative way i.e. one that does not involve loops.

Comment: basically what I'm trying to do is to find q without using a loop.

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you just trying to reshape d? Can you give a smaller, concrete example of what you're trying to do, rather than just your implementation of it.

Comment: I agree with CaptainMurphy, I think you need to use the modulo operator anyhow `I = mod(1:365, 5) + 1`

Comment: Ive tried to make the question as clear as I can

Comment: Ok, it looks like this extracts values from diagonals of your original matrix. Is that what you want?

Comment: Not really, just  extract the value in the column number specified by 'I'

Comment: We're looking for descriptions in english. What determines the contents of I? Now you've changed the question so the contents are random.

Comment: That the entire point, it doesn't matter what I is, I gives a number from one to 5, again it doesn't matter what it is, this number, from 1 to 5, gives the column number that I want (for each row). linear indexing was the way

Comment: For archival purposes/future searches it may be worth editing the title - the fact that it is a time series is irrelevant, the question is really about grabbing a distinct column for each row of a matrix.

Comment: OK, just saying, if your last comment had been in your question, the answer would have come much faster. We can't read your mind. :[

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use linear indexing:

```
ii = 1:length(d);
linear_index = sub2ind(size(d),ii,I(ii));
q = d(linear_index);
```

[sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) converts row (`ii`) and column (`I(ii)`) indices to linear indices, which you can use to grab all the desired elements at once.

Comment: Added 2x transpose to make the variable size match the original example